# can't write unknown attribute `scrapbook_entry_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, model, controller

Attempting to add data to a join table of scrapbook_entries which has_one :scrapbook and has_one :recipe.

:recipe and :scrapbook already exist. I am trying to add them to link them with the scrapbook_entries table.

form_for adding to scrapbook_entries table:

```
<%= form_for(@scrapbook_entry, :url => scrapbook_entries_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%=f.select(:scrapbook_id, current_user.scrapbooks.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },  {prompt: 'Select Scrapbook...'})%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, :value => @recipe.id %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

scrapbook_entries_controller:

```
def create
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:scrapbook_entry][:recipe_id])
    @scrapbook = current_user.scrapbooks.find(params[:scrapbook_entry][:scrapbook_id])

    @entry = @scrapbook.scrapbook_entries.build(scrapbook: @scrapbook)
    if @entry.save
        flash[:success] = "Added '#{@recipe.name}' to scrapbook '#{@scrapbook.name}'"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Could not add to scrapbook"
    end
    redirect_to @recipe
end
```

scrapbook.rb

```
has_many :recipes, through: :scrapbook_entries
has_many :scrapbook_entries
```

recipe.rb

```
has_many :scrapbooks, through: :scrapbook_entries
```

scrapbook_entry.rb

```
has_one :recipe
has_one :scrapbook
```

On submitting the form to the controller I am getting a error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `scrapbook_entry_id'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

schema.rb

```
 create_table "scrapbook_entries", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "scrapbook_id"
   t.integer  "recipe_id"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "user_id"
 end
```

Comment: can you paste the params you are receiving in create actions form the development log

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your scrapbook_entr.rb should contain

```
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :scrapbook
```

and not has_one!

You always use belongs_to when your table contains a foreign key to another table, which in this case definitely is the case!

Comment: Thanks for this. I changed the model. I don't get any errors but I am rendering `flash[:error] = "Could not add to scrapbook"` instead of saving the entry?

Comment: @MikeHolford your `Entry` probably fails validation.

Comment: @DannyVanHoof I have managed to fix it! the entry line needed to be defined with build(:recipe, @recipe) and not scrapbook. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!